# como poner color de fondo a un boton?

Tags: css, botón, fondo

buenas tardes estoy tratando de poner fondo a un boton que cree, pero al ponerlo me sale toda la linea entera de la fila de ese color solo quiero que aparezca en el boton que tengo que modificar ? muchas gracias por su tiempo aqui esta mi html y css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com"  target="_blank">inicio2</a>
</body>
</html>

 css:  a {
    height:  15px 15px;
     display : block;
     width : 20 px;
     font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 200;
     background-color: aquamarine;
     border-radius: 2px;
     padding: 15px 30px;
     margin:  15px 13px;
```

Comment: Como menciona Diego, solamente debes quitarle la propiedad: display:block, puedes leer mas acerca [Display block e inline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Segun el codigo que presentas en tu pregunta, estan mal declaradas las propiedades "height" y "width" de tu elemento "a", es por esto que el elemento al tener un "display: block" abarca la linea completa, por lo que el color que deseas si se esta aplicando correctamente al elemento "a".

Prueba realizando las siguientes modificaciones a tu codigo css a las propiedades de height y width.

```
height:  15px;
width : 20px;
```

La propiedad height debes agregarlo 1 solo valor y la medida en que declaras el valor entregado a la propiedad width no debe contener espacios, si no esta no se reconoce.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estan mal declaradas las propiedades height y width ponlas asi:

```
height: 15px;
width: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `background-color` está bien, solo que no te funcionará porque estás estructurando mal tu clase de css, deberías ser algo así:

```
<style>
  a {
     height:  15px;
     display : block;
     width : 20px;
     font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 200;
     background-color: aquamarine;
     border-radius: 2px;
     padding: 15px 30px;
     margin: 15px 13px;
</style>
```